# Javascript - Function is not defined (onChange doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am calling a function called getPrice() in javascript file by using onChange() command in  tag in HTML file, but no matter what I do or fix, it still doesnt show the price. I have done a lot of research but cant seem to find any correct solutions. Helps will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <body>
            <form action="#" name="ITSbookform" id="ITSform">
                    <fieldset>
                    <legend>Into The Storm Booking</legend>
                    <label>Choose your cinema</label><br>
                    <select id="selectedCinema">
                    <option>--Select--</option>
                    <option value="maximaCinema">Maxima Cinema</option> 
                    <option value="rivolaCinema">Rivola Cinema</option> 
                    </select><br>
                    <label>Select day and time</label>

                    <select id="dayAndTime">

                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <label>Select Seat</label>
                    <select id="selectedSeat" onchange="getPrice()">

                    </select>
                    <p id="total">Total Price: </p>


            </form>
    </fieldset>

    </body>
```

and the Javascipt part:

```
    function getPrice(){
    var totalPrice = 0;
    if(document.getElementById("selectedCinema").value == "maximaCinema"){
        if(document.getElementById("dayAndTime").value == "9pmMonday" || document.getElementById("dayAndTime").value == "9pmTuesday"){
            seatPrice["full"] = 12;
            seatPrice["conc"] = 10;
            seatPrice["child"] = 8;
            seatPrice["FirstClass-Adult"] = 25;
            seatPrice["FirstClass-Child"] = 20;
            seatPrice["beanbag"] = 20;
        }
        else{
            seatPrice["full"] = 18;
            seatPrice["conc"] = 15;
            seatPrice["child"] = 12;
            seatPrice["FirstClass-Adult"] = 30;
            seatPrice["FirstClass-Child"] = 25;
            seatPrice["beanbag"] = 30;
        }
    }
    else{
        seatPrice["adult"] = 18;
        seatPrice["conc"] = 15;
        seatPrice["child"] = 12;
    }

    var seat = theForm.elements["selectedSeat"];
    totalPrice = seatPrice[seat.value];
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "$" + totalPrice;
}
```

and here is the full version of the code in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stb0v5Ln/

Thank you.

Comment: invalid html for `fieldset` is closing after `form`

Comment: You don't have any options available in `select` box., so how will change event will occur and call `getPrice()` function?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar He's injecting them dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use jQuery consistently, your error is using theForm instead of accessing the form again or accessing the form field by ID
2. change the fiddle to head instead of onload

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/kus6t7mn/)

```
var seat = $("#selectedSeat");
totalPrice = seatPrice[seat.val()];
$("#total").html("$" + totalPrice);
```

Also remove the onchange from the tag and add

```
$("#selectedSeat").change(getPrice);
```

to the ready

ps: remove all head and body tags when creating a fiddle

Answer (score 2):

First of all the fiddle is set to run `onload` - so it'll wrap your code in an onload handler - so the function `getPrice()` will not be available globally.

Which will cause the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getPrice is not defined
```

Setting the fiddle to no-wrap will fix this issue.

Other than that, JavaScript has function level scope - You've declared the variable `var theForm = document.forms["ITSform"];` inside `ready()` function and you're trying to access it out side in `getPrice()` function. Which will cause:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: theForm is not defined
```

Either make the variable global or move the function `getPrice()` inside `ready()`

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/stb0v5Ln/4/)

Simply checking for errors in browser console will help you solve these kind of issues.

Answer (score 1):

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/stb0v5Ln/5/)

removed `<fieldset>` which was not closing proper

and moved the `theForm` variable inside `getPrice()` because it was not getting the variable function and fixed